# Getting a Warning when I build my app on the device - What does this mean?

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings

could someone please help me with this warning. I get this on my console when I do a buildandRun on my device rather than my simulator. What exactly does the last line mean?
I'm using XCode 3.2. Should I be concerned about this when I deploy my apps to the app store?

Console Printout:

```
========================================================
[Session started at 2011-04-18 07:59:37 -0400.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys001
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-408-54
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue

    Warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's fine. It's just a warning, and one from the debugger (not the compiler). This won't affect the app when published on the App Store and it's unlikley to cause any problems while developing either.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the path and delete this folder -

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/

and when you will connect your device again it will ask you to recollect the os, so press collect.